# How to draw/cut up two rings so that their segments are interchangeable

Tags: drawing

I have 2 rings, an inner ring and an outer ring.

How do I Cut them up into segments such that the segments of the two rings are interchangeable (i.e. identical)?

[image]

So each ring must be the same thickness and each segment must be the same size but the outer ring can have a greater number of segments than the inner ring.

So how to I cut up these to rings so that A and B are interchangeable and how do I scale this method when more rings are added?

Comment: What program are you using? Can you provide a sample image of what you'd like to achieve? As it is, your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: @fred is right it can not be done.

Comment: They are cut at different angles.

Answer (score 4):

As per your drawing, the inner ring outer diameter is either exactly the same as the outer ring inner diameter or is slightly smaller.

Because of this characteristic, you will not be able to interchange Ring A segments with Ring B segments.

If this is an unacceptable answer, please consider that the parameters of your question have to be adjusted appropriately.